# Could not find vectorDrawbles

Tags: android, android-studio, vector, gradle

I created a project in android studio and I did not put a code on it. But when I try to install it on my cellphone jelly bean(4.2.2) version. It returns "Exception while inflating ". 
I got this error

```
08-04 15:18:38.377  15045-15045/? E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:708)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:348)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at dunhill.diary_sarah.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: Gradle version]

[image: SDK version]

[image]

I'm tried to add "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" on android default config but still not working. also put this code on build.gradle. "generatedDensities = []" and "aaptOptions { additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" }". I got this error "Error:(13, 0) No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm tried to add "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true"

In order to use it, you need at lease version 2 of the android gradle plugin. At the moment you are using 1.3. You should also avoid mixing versions when it comes to `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersions` and `support library`.

Comment: I also put this code on build.gradle. "generatedDensities = []" and "aaptOptions { additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" }". I got this error "Error:(13, 0) No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated"

Comment: don't mix things. For that you need at least version 1.5 of thte  android plugin. You are using 1.3

Comment: So what I'm gonna do? I got this error if I didn't modify the build.gradle "Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl"